# Internationalization using Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I followed this [tutorial](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) to create a multi-language app in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Everything is fine, but now I'm having some trouble to get this from database.

I have one class with `Description_en` and `Description_pt` properties. I want to print in the view the property corresponding to the selected language.

I would like to have something like this `@item.Description_ + culture.` I made this working like this:

```
@(culture == "pt" ? @item.Description_pt : @item.Description_en);
```

But it'll be complicated when I add more languages.

How to make this more effective for more languages? Or is there a better approach to save to the database?

Comment: what is your database being accessed with? perhaps you should structure your view model better.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's about the database?  Seems like you are trying to figure out how make the view so that it can receive data that is localized for one locale and display it?  I think, you're not going to want your classes to contain different values for different locales, your going to want to set things up so that your class ends up with the values for one particular locale before it ever gets passed to the view.

Comment: exactly that, any suggestions how I can do that?